# write file on the UI or background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask and i want to write data to a file.

should I write data to the file in UI thread "OnProgressUpdate" or on the background thread "doInBackground"

Comment: Write in doInBackground(), if your file size is large.

Comment: _writing data to a file_ has nothing to do with the UI. Then it should be in a background thread.

Comment: Read the AsyncTask docs, onProgressUpdate is meant to just notify the user about the current action progress, all task should be done in doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

> onProgressUpdate() is used to operate progress of asynchronous operations via this method
>
> This callback can be triggered from within the body of the doInBackground() method by calling publishProgress()

Reading and Writing is always better to do in background thread. Well it's always a better UX!

Answer (score 1):

No second thought. Do it in doInBackground().